# Is there a faster way of doing full row comparisons on a small pandas dataframe than using loops and iloc?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a large number of small pandas dataframes on which I have to do full row comparisons and write the results into new dataframes which will get concatenated later.

For the row comparisons I'm doing a double loop over the length of the dataframe using iloc. I don't know if there is a faster way, the way I'm doing it seems really slow:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import time

def processFrames1(DF):
  LL = []
  for i in range(len(DF)):
    for j in range(len(DF)):
      if DF.iloc[i][0] != DF.iloc[j][0]:
        T = {u'T1':DF.iloc[i][0]}
        T[u'T2'] = DF.iloc[j][0]
        T[u'T3'] = 1
        if DF.iloc[i][2] > DF.iloc[j][2]:
          T[u'T4'] = 1
        elif DF.iloc[i][2] < DF.iloc[j][2]:
          T[u'T4'] = -1
        else:
          T[u'T4'] = 0
        if DF.iloc[i][1] < DF.iloc[j][1]:
          T[u'T5'] = 1
        else:
          T[u'T5'] = -1
        LL.append(T)
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(LL)

D = [{'A':'XA','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'RT','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'HO','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'NJ','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'WF','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'DV','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'KP','B':7,'C':2.4}]

P = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D)
time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  X = processFrames1(P)
print time.time()-time0
print X
```

Yielding the result:

```
0.836999893188
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
0   XA  RT   1  -1   1
1   XA  HO   1  -1   1
2   XA  NJ   1   1   1
3   XA  WF   1  -1   1
4   XA  DV   1  -1   1
5   XA  KP   1  -1   1
6   RT  XA   1   1  -1
7   RT  HO   1  -1   1
8   RT  NJ   1   1   1
9   RT  WF   1  -1   1
10  RT  DV   1  -1   1
11  RT  KP   1   1   1
12  HO  XA   1   1  -1
13  HO  RT   1   1  -1
14  HO  NJ   1   1   1
15  HO  WF   1  -1   1
16  HO  DV   1  -1   1
17  HO  KP   1   1   1
18  NJ  XA   1  -1  -1
19  NJ  RT   1  -1  -1
20  NJ  HO   1  -1  -1
21  NJ  WF   1  -1   1
22  NJ  DV   1  -1   1
23  NJ  KP   1  -1   1
24  WF  XA   1   1  -1
25  WF  RT   1   1  -1
26  WF  HO   1   1  -1
27  WF  NJ   1   1  -1
28  WF  DV   1   1   1
29  WF  KP   1   1   1
30  DV  XA   1   1  -1
31  DV  RT   1   1  -1
32  DV  HO   1   1  -1
33  DV  NJ   1   1  -1
34  DV  WF   1  -1  -1
35  DV  KP   1   1   1
36  KP  XA   1   1  -1
37  KP  RT   1  -1  -1
38  KP  HO   1  -1  -1
39  KP  NJ   1   1  -1
40  KP  WF   1  -1  -1
41  KP  DV   1  -1  -1
```

Working this representative dataframe just 10 times takes almost a full second, and I will have to work with over a million.

Is there a faster way to do those full row comparisons?

EDIT1:
After some modifications I could make Javier's code create the correct output:

```
def compare_values1(x,y):
  if x>y: return 1
  elif x<y: return -1
  else: return 0

def compare_values2(x,y):
  if x<y: return 1
  elif x>y: return -1
  else: return 0

def processFrames(P):
  D = P.to_dict(orient='records')
  d_A2B = {d["A"]:d["B"] for d in D}
  d_A2C = {d["A"]:d["C"] for d in D}
  keys = list(d_A2B.keys())
  LL = []
  for i in range(len(keys)):
    k_i = keys[i]
    for j in range(len(keys)):
      if i != j:
        k_j = keys[j]
        LL.append([k_i,k_j,1,compare_values1(\
         d_A2C[k_i],d_A2C[k_j]),compare_values2(d_A2B[k_i],d_A2B[k_j])])
  return pd.DataFrame(LL,columns=['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5'])
```

This function works about 60 times faster.

EDIT2:
Final verdict of the four possibilities:

=============== With the small dataframe:

My original function:

```
%timeit processFrames1(P)
10 loops, best of 3: 85.3 ms per loop
```

jezrael's solution:

```
%timeit processFrames2(P)
1 loop, best of 3: 286 ms per loop
```

Javier's modified code:

```
%timeit processFrames3(P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 ms per loop
```

Divakar's method:

```
%timeit processFrames4(P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 ms per loop
```

=============== For the large dataframe:

My original function:

```
%timeit processFrames1(P)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.22 s per loop
```

jezrael's solution:

```
%timeit processFrames2(P)
1 loop, best of 3: 295 ms per loop
```

Javier's modified code:

```
%timeit processFrames3(P)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop
```

Divakar's method:

```
%timeit processFrames4(P)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.19 ms per loop
```

So it's pretty much a tie between the last two. Thanks to everyone for helping, that speedup was much needed.

EDIT 3:

Divakar has edited their code and this is the new result:

Small dataframe:

```
%timeit processFrames(P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 492 µs per loop
```

Large dataframe:

```
%timeit processFrames(P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 844 µs per loop
```

Very impressive and the absolute winner.

EDIT 4:

Divakar's method slightly modified as I am using it in my program now:

```
def processFrames(P):
  N = len(P)
  N_range = np.arange(N)
  valid_mask = (N_range[:,None] != N_range).ravel()
  colB = P.B.values
  colC = P.C.values
  T2_arr = np.ones(N*N,dtype=int)
  T4_arr = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=int)
  T4_arr[colC[:,None] > colC] = 1
  T4_arr[colC[:,None] < colC] = -1
  T5_arr = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=int)
  T5_arr[colB[:,None] > colB] = -1
  T5_arr[colB[:,None] < colB] = 1
  strings = P.A.values
  c0,c1 = np.meshgrid(strings,strings)
  arr = np.column_stack((c1.ravel(), c0.ravel(), T2_arr,T4_arr.ravel(),\
                         T5_arr.ravel()))[valid_mask]
  return arr[:,0],arr[:,1],arr[:,2],arr[:,3],arr[:,4]
```

I'm creating a dictionary with five keys containing a list each which represent the five resulting columns, then I just extend the lists with the results, and once I'm done I'm making a pandas dataframe from the dictionary. That's a much faster way than to concatenate to an existing dataframe.

PS: The one thing I learned from this: Never use iloc if you can avoid it in any way.

Comment: Instead of converting to dictionary, do this:
`d_A2B = dict(zip(P["A"],P["B"))`;`d_A2C = dict(zip(P["A"],P["C"))`

Comment: And you'll save half the time if you leave the for loops as I had them:
`for j in range(i+1,len(keys)):`
and then `c2 = compare_values2(d_A2B[k_i],d_A2B[k_j])`; `c1 = compare_values1(d_A2C[k_i],d_A2C[k_j])`; `LL.append([k_i,k_j,1,c1,c2])`; `LL.append([k_j,k_i,1,-c1,-c2])`.

Comment: I'll also lose half of the data if I'm doing `for j in range(i+1)`.

Comment: No, because comparing i,j and j,i is exactly the same (but changing the sign of c1 and c2). That's why there are two append lines.

Comment: I see, now I understand your loop. I tried your modifications but they didn't yield any more speedup. They're small dataframes after all.

Comment: @Khris Could edit the timings with my updated solution? Sorry for the troubles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def processFrames1_broadcasting(P):

    N = len(P)
    N_range = np.arange(N)
    valid_mask = (N_range[:,None] != N_range).ravel()

    colB = P.B.values
    colC = P.C.values

    T2_arr = np.ones(N*N,dtype=int)

    T4_arr = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=int)
    T4_arr[colC[:,None] > colC] = 1
    T4_arr[colC[:,None] < colC] = -1

    T5_arr = np.where(colB[:,None] < colB,1,-1)

    strings = P.A.values
    c0,c1 = np.meshgrid(strings,strings)


    arr = np.column_stack((c1.ravel(), c0.ravel(), T2_arr,T4_arr.ravel(),\
                            T5_arr.ravel()))[valid_mask]

    df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=[['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5']])

    return df
```

Runtime test -

For the sample posted in the question, the runtimes I got at my end are -

```
In [337]: %timeit processFrames1(P)
10 loops, best of 3: 93.1 ms per loop

In [338]: %timeit processFrames1_jezrael(P) #@jezrael's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 74.8 ms per loop

In [339]: %timeit processFrames1_broadcasting(P)
1000 loops, best of 3: 561 µs per loop
```

Comment: :) so numpy win ;)

Comment: Thanks, your solution is around a factor of 42 faster.

Comment: @Khris Check out the updated solution too! As it turns out creating daraframe in one go is much faster than editing it on per column basis.

Comment: @Divakar: I'm impressed, your code is now the fastest, see me last edit of my post. I'm also surprised how much faster that code is compared to pandas, I thought pandas dataframes were built on numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pandas. Use dictionaries and save it:

```
def compare_values(x,y):
  if x>y: return 1
  elif x<y: return -1
  else: return 0

def processFrames(P):
  d_A2B = dict(zip(P["A"],P["B"]))
  d_A2C = dict(zip(P["A"],P["C"]))

  keys = list(d_A2B.keys())
  d_ind2key = dict(zip(range(len(keys)),keys))
  LL = []
  for i in range(len(keys)):
    k_i = keys[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(keys)):
        k_j = keys[j]
        c1 = compare_values(d_A2C[k_i],d_A2C[k_j])
        c2 = -compare_values(d_A2B[k_i],d_A2B[k_j])
        LL.append([k_i,k_j,1,c1,c2])
        LL.append([k_j,k_i,1,-c1,-c2])
  return pd.DataFrame(LL,columns=['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5'])
```

Comment: What are you starting with @Khris?

Comment: What I need is a new data frame, your solution ends with a file. Are you saying I should save to file then read in the file into a new dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it'll be 50 times faster than your code. You can write the dataframe line by line but that's slow.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get it right, you had a mistake in the index. It's about a factor of 60 faster, thanks a lot for the tip. Will edit my question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#cross join
P['one'] = 1
df = pd.merge(P,P, on='one')
df = df.rename(columns={'A_x':'T1','A_y':'T2'})

#remove duplicates
df = df[df.T1 != df.T2]
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#creates new columns
df['T3'] = 1
df['T4'] = (df.C_x > df.C_y).astype(int).replace({0:-1})
df['T5'] = (df.B_x < df.B_y).astype(int).replace({0:-1})
#remove other columns by subset
df = df[['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5']]
print (df)
```

```
    T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
0   XA  RT   1  -1   1
1   XA  HO   1  -1   1
2   XA  NJ   1   1   1
3   XA  WF   1  -1   1
4   XA  DV   1  -1   1
5   XA  KP   1  -1   1
6   RT  XA   1   1  -1
7   RT  HO   1  -1   1
8   RT  NJ   1   1   1
9   RT  WF   1  -1   1
10  RT  DV   1  -1   1
11  RT  KP   1   1   1
12  HO  XA   1   1  -1
13  HO  RT   1   1  -1
14  HO  NJ   1   1   1
15  HO  WF   1  -1   1
16  HO  DV   1  -1   1
17  HO  KP   1   1   1
18  NJ  XA   1  -1  -1
19  NJ  RT   1  -1  -1
20  NJ  HO   1  -1  -1
21  NJ  WF   1  -1   1
22  NJ  DV   1  -1   1
23  NJ  KP   1  -1   1
24  WF  XA   1   1  -1
25  WF  RT   1   1  -1
26  WF  HO   1   1  -1
27  WF  NJ   1   1  -1
28  WF  DV   1   1   1
29  WF  KP   1   1   1
30  DV  XA   1   1  -1
31  DV  RT   1   1  -1
32  DV  HO   1   1  -1
33  DV  NJ   1   1  -1
34  DV  WF   1  -1  -1
35  DV  KP   1   1   1
36  KP  XA   1   1  -1
37  KP  RT   1  -1  -1
38  KP  HO   1  -1  -1
39  KP  NJ   1   1  -1
40  KP  WF   1  -1  -1
41  KP  DV   1  -1  -1
```

**TIMINGS**:

```
In [339]: %timeit processFrames1(P)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.2 ms per loop

In [340]: %timeit jez(P1)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.3 ms per loop
```

If use your timings:

```
time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  X = processFrames1(P)
print (time.time()-time0)
0.4760475158691406

time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  X = jez(P1)
print (time.time()-time0)
0.4400441646575928
```

Code for testing:

```
P1 = P.copy()

def jez(P):
    P['one'] = 1
    df = pd.merge(P,P, on='one')
    df = df.rename(columns={'A_x':'T1','A_y':'T2'})

    df = df[df.T1 != df.T2]
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df['T3'] = 1
    df['T4'] = (df.C_x > df.C_y).astype(int).replace({0:-1})
    df['T5'] = (df.B_x < df.B_y).astype(int).replace({0:-1})
    df = df[['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5']]
    return (df)

def processFrames1(DF):
  LL = []
  for i in range(len(DF)):
    for j in range(len(DF)):
      if DF.iloc[i][0] != DF.iloc[j][0]:
        T = {u'T1':DF.iloc[i][0]}
        T[u'T2'] = DF.iloc[j][0]
        T[u'T3'] = 1
        if DF.iloc[i][2] > DF.iloc[j][2]:
          T[u'T4'] = 1
        elif DF.iloc[i][2] < DF.iloc[j][2]:
          T[u'T4'] = -1
        else:
          T[u'T4'] = 0
        if DF.iloc[i][1] < DF.iloc[j][1]:
          T[u'T5'] = 1
        else:
          T[u'T5'] = -1
        LL.append(T)
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(LL)
```

EDIT1:

I try test in 5 times bigger dataFrame:

```
D = [{'A':'XA','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'RB','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'HC','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'ND','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'WE','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'DF','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'KG','B':7,'C':2.4}\
    ,{'A':'XH','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'RI','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'HJ','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'NK','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'WL','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'DM','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'KN','B':7,'C':2.4}\
    ,{'A':'XO','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'RP','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'HQ','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'NR','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'WS','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'DT','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'KU','B':7,'C':2.4}\
    ,{'A':'XV','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'RW','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'HX','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'NY','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'WZ','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'D1','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'K2','B':7,'C':2.4}\
    ,{'A':'X3','B':1,'C':1.4}\
    ,{'A':'R4','B':2,'C':10}\
    ,{'A':'H5','B':3,'C':34}\
    ,{'A':'N6','B':4,'C':0.41}\
    ,{'A':'W7','B':5,'C':114}\
    ,{'A':'D8','B':6,'C':74}\
    ,{'A':'K9','B':7,'C':2.4}    ]

P = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D)
```

```
P1 = P.copy()

time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  X = processFrames1(P)
print (time.time()-time0)
12.230222940444946

time0 = time.time()
for i in range(10):
  X = jez(P1)
print (time.time()-time0)
0.4440445899963379
```

```
In [351]: %timeit processFrames1(P)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop

In [352]: %timeit jez(P1)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: I believe creating `P = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(D)` is the slowest part of the code.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks, but I'm afraid your code is over three times slower than mine.

Comment: Interesting - my timeit show it is a bit faster - `In [339]: %timeit processFrames1(P)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.2 ms per loop

In [340]: %timeit jez(P1)
10 loops, best of 3: 43.3 ms per loop`

Comment: Maybe because python 3, for me it show `your code - 0.49504947662353516, my code
0.450045108795166`

Comment: It is really interesting, for me it show a bit faster code.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Python 2, that might make the difference.

Comment: What about a bit bigger dataframe? it is still very slow in python 2? see my edit.

Comment: Interesting, now yours is over 5 times faster than mine. The other two solutions are much much faster though.

Comment: Ok, can I delete my solution?

Comment: I'm referencing it in my final edit of my question, so I'd prefer if it stayed. But if you don't want it to be here feel free to delete it.

Comment: If solution is upvote, I dont delete it. In pure pandas I get no other idea for improving. But I think the best is use numpy, becasue it is the faster, but a bit complicated. Good luck!